# Calculates the probability that in the two subsets of the retrieval there are only two identical elements

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For the set $ A $ has $ 6 $ elements. Take a random $ 2 $ subset from the subsets of the set $ A $. Calculates the probability that in the two subsets of the retrieval there are only two same elements.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. It is very difficult to understand what you are asking in itself, without giving more information about the problem by telling us which concepts you are having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I managed to understand this question, it actually means:

Suppose $A$ is a set, $|A| = 6$. $\mathcal{P}(A) $ is the set of all subsets of $A$. Suppose $B$ and $C$ are two independent random elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ under discrete uniform distribution. What is the probability of $|B \cap C| = 1$?

If my interpretation is correct, then the question can be solved that way:

Suppose $x$ is the number of ordered pairs of subsets of A satisfying that condition and $y$ is the number of ordered pairs of disjoint subsets of a 5 element set. Then, the probability we are looking for is $\frac{x}{(2^6)^2}$. Suppose $a \in A$, $B \cap C = \{a\}$, then $B\setminus\{a\}, C\setminus\{a\}$ are disjoint subsets of $A\setminus\{a\}$. We can choose a in 6 different ways and that results in $x = 6y$. Now the only thing is left - to find $y$.

Suppose $U, V \subset D$, $|D| = 5$, $U \cap V = \emptyset$. Then if $|U| = n$, $n \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, then there are $\frac{5!}{n!(5-n)!}$ possible subsets fitting the description of U, and $2^(5-n) $- of $V$. That means $y = 32 + 80 + 80 + 40 + 10 + 1  = 243 = 3^5$.
That results in the probability, we were looking for, being equal to $\frac{3^6}{2^{11}}$